# How do i filter words starting with uppercase in bash scripting? I have a text.txt , and i want to finde only the words starting with Uppercase (Nnnn)

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to find just the words starting with a letter in Uppercase. The words must follow this patern. "Nnnnn".

I have a file .txt whit a text.
I tried using grep but didnt succeed.

Comment: Welcome, please [edit] the question adding what have you tried. **Don't do it in comments.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want a uppercase letter followed by 4 characters, this one for e.g.:

```
$ cat test
lower
Upper
notrequired
This1
$ grep '[A-Z]....' test
Upper
This1
```

a dot (`.`) matches any character other than newline.

Answer (score 1):

If your `grep` supports the non-standard `-w` and `-o` options, you could do:

```bash
grep -wo '[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*'
```

to `o`utput the `w`ords (words in that case delimited by non-word characters, word characters being alnums or underscores) that consist of one uppercase letter followed by 0 or more lowercase ones.

For instance, on an input like:

```
Let's rock the UK, Stéphane! tEst Test2
```

It outputs:

```
Let
Stéphane
```

as long as that `é` is expressed as the single lower case U+00E9 character. If it was expressed as `e` followed by the U+0301 combining acute accent, You'd get `Let` and `Ste` instead as U+0301 is not considered as a *word character*.

You might want to also accept the combining marks to work around that, for which you'd need a `grep` with `perl`-like regex support:

```bash
grep -Po '\G(\X*(?=[^\w])\X)?\K\p{Lu}[\p{Ll}\pM]*+(?!\w)'
```

Where:

- `\G` matches at the start of the line or following the end of the previous match.
- `\X` matches a grapheme cluster so would include the base character and all combining marks (or more generally decomposed characters), without allowing them to be broken appart.
- `(?=[^\w])\X` is a grapheme cluster led by a non-word character, to make sure the word we find is properly delimited like with `grep -w` so that for instance `Foo` be not reported if found in `éFoo` including then the é is expressed as `e<U+0301>`.
- `\K` resets the start of the match so we `K`eep (and `o`utput) only what's on the right of it. Using `\G` in combination with `\K` is often used to work around the fact that look behind operators on work with fixed length matches in perl/PCRE.
- `\p{Lu}` matches characters with the `u`ppercase `L`etter `p`roperty, the perl equivalent of POSIX' `[[:upper:]]`.
- `\pM` for `M`arks, `\p{Ll}` for `l`owercase `L`etters.
- `*+` is like `*` but forbids backtracking so that all the marks and lowercase letters are included for good, so we don't need to worry about marks in:
- `(?!\w)`, a negative look ahead for a *word character*. If we didn't have the `+` above, we'd need `(?![\w\pM])` to avoid `Fe` be returned in `FéF` for instance (with `é` as `eU+0301`).

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
grep -o "\b[[:upper:]].*\b" file
```

The `-o` option will output the found matches only, and the `\b` will make sure we're only considering entire words `man grep`:

> The symbol \b matches the empty string at the edge of a word

Answer (score 0):

This worked with me and may help you too:

```
for i in $(cat file); do [[ $i =~ ^[A-Z].[a-z]+$ ]] && echo $i; done
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with for](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) Also in this case is not necessary using any loop since you can use a text processing tool such as `grep` (which is already covered by all the other answers)

Comment: Related "in-house" caution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/377345.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am beginner in this field and I need such advices.